# PHP- Codeigniter Redirect to admin and user based on user role

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

If the admin is logging in, I want them to go to admin page, otherwise to appointments page. In the users table, I have a column of 'id_roles' and the value are '2' and '3'. 2 stands for admin and 3 stands for user and there is separate table for role.

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    // get form input
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    // form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email-ID", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation fail
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else
    {
        // check for user credentials
        $uresult = $this->model_user->get_user($email, $password);
        //edit
        if (count($uresult) > 0 )
        {
            // set session

            $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->first_name,'ulname' => $uresult[0]->last_name,'uemail' => $uresult[0]->email, 'uphone' => $uresult[0]->phone_number, 'uaddress' => $uresult[0]->address, 'ucity' => $uresult[0]->city,  'uin' => $uresult[0]->injury, 'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            //edit

        if($uresult->['id_roles'] == 3)
            redirect('appoinments/index');
            else 
            redirect('admin/index');

        }

        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
    function get_user($email, $pwd)
{
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($pwd));
    $query = $this->db->get('ea_users');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: `$uresult->id_roles` not `['id_roles']`. Your model should also return a `$query->row()` since you'd likely to only have one result, that way you don't have to use indexes to access the fields.

Comment: I have made your changes, my problem now is that its redirecting to a blank page. End of url being 'login/index'. If i leave the model as original it will only redirect to the 'admin' page

Comment: If you updated your model you also need to update the data you're setting for your session as you are using numbered indexes which would not exist. If you are getting a white screen of death you need to enable error reporting,

Comment: I included the indexes in the if statement and it worked. if($uresult[0]->id_roles ==3). Thank you for pointing out the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In your "ea_users" table create another column "usertype". For login when you will retrieve the data according to usertype you can redirect (i.e. user profile and admin panel for user and admin respectively)

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant, as in the question itself @lainey has explained about the user type. You have just written the question again in your answer. Do read the question properly before posting the answer.